# Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Hello everyone I'm working with an app and I'm consuming rest api using retrofit2. I have a list of companies that I need to show using recyclerview. I have followed a lot of resources and tutorials but none helped me. In the logcat session I have an error:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference in my adapter....

in this line :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return companies.size();
}
```

Here is my code: 
my adapter

```
private List<Company> companies;
private Context context;

public CompanyAdapter(List<Company> companies, Context context) {
    this.companies = companies;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_companies, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Company comp = companies.get(position);

    viewHolder.compName.setText(comp.getName());
    viewHolder.compDesc.setText(comp.getDescription());
    viewHolder.compNipt.setText(comp.getNipt());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return companies.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView compName, compDesc, compNipt;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        compName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyName);
        compDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyDescription);
        compNipt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyNipt);
    }
}
```

and my activity

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<Company> companies;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_companies_list);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.companies_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter = new CompanyAdapter(companies, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong...
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: From your description, it seems obvious that `companies` is null. You write that you have this list, but I don't see any code that initializes it.

Comment: there: private List<Company> companies;

Comment: I red this link before asking the question, but I'm missing something and also I'm new to java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return companies == null ? 0 : companies.size()
}
```